# fatal: couldn't read .git/packed-refs: invalid argument

Tags: git

When initializing a new repository using 'git init', any further operations (such as 'git status' or 'git add .') is blocked by an error reading the title.

There is no .git/packed-ref file inside the folder.
All folders are empty.
Window ver. = 21H2
Git ver.    = 2.36.2

This problem does not occur when creating repositories on the base C drive, but when attempting to create repositories or switch branches using github desktop on the larger, external drive, git refuses to cooperate.

The external drive is NTFS. An attempt at making it on an NTFS 128gb USB has also yielded the same results.

Steps to replicate:

1. Create directory
2. Initialize git
3. Attempt to use 'git status'

I need to use git from the external hard drive because my base memory on my computer is too small to handle manual compiling of UE4. This happens as well when attempting to commit a C# console application, but moving the C# application to the downloads folder allows me to create a proper repository. [Here is the relevant output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKE0K.png)

Additional output

```
PS D:\Project\MongoDBConnection> git fsck --full  
warning: unable to access '.git/objects/info/alternates': Invalid argument  
error: unable to open .git/objects/00: Invalid argument  

Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.  

fatal: couldn't read .git/packed-refs: Invalid argument
```

Tried sending the .git folder to someone else and they were able to use .git status and any other .git operations without issue.

Comment: What this all means is that the host in which you've created the Git repository (the `.git` directory) is refusing to let Git read the `.git` directory, even though it's allowing other programs to read the `.git` directory. That's not a Git problem: that's a host setup error of some sort.

Comment: Do you have a non-default antivirus on this system?  Do you maybe have some sort of process monitoring this external drive?  Is this external drive synced to a cloud-syncing service?

Comment: The default antivirus is the only antivirus on the computer. There is no process monitoring that I've turned on. The external drive is not hooked up to a cloud syncing service.